# Copy java/xml code from Notepad++ to Ms word

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, notepad++

I have wrote a .doc document and I want to paste xml code in Ms Word.
I tried to copy the xml code in Notepad++ but I don't know how insert the line numbers and the vertical line as  in this picture.
How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but you probably want Apache POI for this.

Comment: I want to write in a document .doc the same as shows  this photo. Code+ line numbers+vertical line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Result in Word:**

[image]

**Steps:**

1. In Word, create table with 1 row and 2 columns. Left column will be for line numbers, right column for XML code.

**Get XML code into right column:**

1. In Notepad++, select desired XML.
2. Use menu **Plugins** > **NppExport** > **Copy all formats to clipboard** (if you don't have that plugin, install it using **Plugin Manager** plugin)
3. Paste exported selection to right column of your Word table.

**Get line numbers into left column:**

1. In Notepad++, open search window and use

   - **Search mode** = **Regular Expression**
   - **". matches newline"** = **Off**
   - **Find what** = `.*`
   - **Replace with** = (empty field)
   - Press **Replace all** button.
2. Menu **Edit** > **Column Editor**: set **Initial Number** = 1, **Increase by** = 1 and confirm
3. Using NppExport plugin, export all generated line numbers into left column of your Word table. This will give them the same font as used in code.
4. Align numbers in left column to the right.
5. Undo search/replace in Notepad++ to get your XML file content back.

**Finalization:**

1. In Word, change outside border of the table to invisible so only vertical divider remains visible.

NOTE: this is easy way how to do it without programming. Do not expect automatic way, Word is not a web page where code gets formatted automatically. Web pages supporting code snippets use specially developed program to format inserted source code, insert line numbers etc.